# Reset Autoplay of Owl Carousel when user manually skip to next slide

Tags: slider, timeout, owl-carousel, autoplay, owl-carousel-2

Hey guys i'm having issues an Owl Carousel, it doesn't reset the Autoplay Timeout when user skips to the next slide. The slides changes each 5 seconds, nevertheless when an user change it manualy to the second slide after 2.5 secs, the slide changes again to quickly and it's annoying .

Anyone knows the solution? Please.

I leave the code down below

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var tiempo = $('.datos-slider').attr("data-time")+'000';
  var tipo = $('.datos-slider').attr("data-tipo");
  
  console.log(tiempo);
  $('.owl-carousel.carousel-principal').owlCarousel({
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout: tiempo ,
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    items:1,
    nav:tipo == 1 ? true:false,
    dots:tipo == 2 ? true:false,
    pullDrag:false,
  });
```

I tried to set stop the the autoplay with the next function:

```
    owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
        owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
        owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
```

But it doesn't work. I'm expecting to restart the time to 0 when someone changes the slide manually by clicking on the dots